# Tank_auth set_value() undefined on custom login page

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

On the default tank_auth login view, there are no errors whatsoever. However, I wanted to style it to match the rest of the site, so I took the code and pasted it into a custom login page (thus replacing the form element, but leaving everything else). However, I end up with this error where the form element should be:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function set_value() in
>   /home/tester/public_html/testsite/application/views/login.php on line
>   247

I should note that the view is not in the /auth/ directory, like the default tank_auth login view is. Does it have to be moved, or is there a way to use it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in config/autoload.php load form helper this will work set_value is part of form helper